# Uniform Convergence of Electric Field Integral

Tags: improper-integrals, uniform-convergence, mathematical-physics, stokes-theorem

I'm working on mathematically proving the Gauss' Law, and I'm having proving the approximations of the electric field integral converge uniformly. The steps are:

First I take discrete charges $q_i$ at locations $a_i\in \mathbb{R}^3$. The electric field is $$E(x)=\underset{i=1}{\overset{k}{\sum}}\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon}q_{i}\frac{\underline{x}-\underline{a}_{i}}{||\underline{x}-\underline{a}_{i}||^{3}}$$
where $\varepsilon$ is the vacuum permittivity. For an open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ if $\partial U$ is a smooth surface taking the surface integral of the second kind yields: $$\iint_{\partial U}E\cdot\hat{n}dS=\underset{\{i;q_{i}\in U\}}{\sum}\frac{q_i}{\varepsilon}$$

Next, we look at a charge density $\rho(x)$, continuous on the closure of an open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^3$. The electric field now takes an integral form:$$E(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon}\int_{U}\frac{x-y}{||x-y||^{3}}\rho(y)dy$$
I use approximations for the field - Taking cubes of sidelength $s$ centered at $s\mathbb{Z}^3$ we consider the cubes $\{C_i\}$ fully contained in $U$, and approximate the integrand by it's value at the centre point $\frac{x-a_{i}}{||x-a_{i}||^{3}}\rho(a_{i})$.
I am able to show that we have pointwise convergence: $$E(x)=\lim_{s\rightarrow0}\underset{i}{\sum}\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{C_{i}}\frac{x-a_{i}}{||x-a_{i}||^{3}}\rho(a_{i})dy=\frac{1}{4\pi}\cdot\lim_{s\rightarrow0}\underset{i}{\underset{i}{\sum}\frac{x-a_{i}}{||x-a_{i}||^{3}}\rho(a_{i})Vol(C_{i})}$$
I want to use the first result, and push the surface integral through the electric field integral to get: $$\iint_{\partial U}E\cdot\hat{n}dS=\frac{1}{4\pi}\cdot\underset{i}{\sum}4\pi\rho(a_{i})Vol(C_{i})=\lim_{s\rightarrow0}\underset{i}{\sum}\rho(a_{i})Vol(C_{i})=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\iiint_{U}\rho$$
$$\rightarrow \iint_{\partial U}E\cdot\hat{n}dS=\frac{Q_{in}}{\varepsilon}$$
which is Gauss' Law.

The problem is I can't seem to be able to prove uniform convergence of these approximations. The integrand is not continuous and goes to $\infty$ when $x=y$, and I don't know how to work it to get uniform convergence. Any help will be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Well, the quick way of justifying it is to use the divergence theorem: $\int_{\partial U}E\cdot n\,dA=\int_U\text{div}(E)\,dV=\int_U\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\rho\,dV=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$. So, you have to justify why the divergence of $E$ is $\rho/\epsilon_0$ from the given integral formula.

Comment: @peek-a-boo The question actually specifically asks to for going in this order and then to conclude that $divE=\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon}$. But that's a good idea generally, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I think we have to assume something about the field for the integral to be given by that limit.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins We have the assumption that $\rho(x)$ is continuous on $cl(U)$, you think we need more than that?

Comment: I think that's enough because then the integral is guaranteed to exist, except perhaps at $x$. That is easily fixed by requiring $\rho$ bounded and that $\rho$ decays sufficiently rapidly at $x$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, the vector field $x \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|^{3}}$ is locally integrable in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: "goes to $\infty$ when $x = y$"  Hint: how can a sequence of functions that is not locally bounded converge to a (locally) bounded one?  You will not be able to get uniform convergence as $s \to 0^{+}$.

Comment: @Peter Morfe When I showed point-wise convergence at point $x$ I took out a small neighbourhood of $x$ away so the approximations would be bounded - but I don't see a way this can be done in a uniformly so maybe you're right.